# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/tasks.1")

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I'm following a tutorial on a TODO-application using Rails 4.2.1 on my local environment.

The problem:  `/task.1`, but it should be `/task/1`. is solve by Nithin.
Also I edited "resource :tasks" to ":task" in config/routes.rb.

And these solved the "edit" issue!!!

But still get some kind of routing error on "delete". Why?

**Tasks_controller**

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js

  # GET /tasks
  # GET /tasks.json
  def new
    @task = Task.new    
    render :show_form
  end

  # POST /task
  # POST /task.json
  def create
    @task = Task.create(task_params)
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  # GET /task
  # GET /task.json
  def edit
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    render :show_form
  end

  # DELETE /task
  # DELETE /task.json
  def destory
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.destroy
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  private

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:title, :note, :completed)
  end
end
```

**_task_list.html.erb**

```
<% if @tasks.empty? %>
  <span class="text-warning">There are no tasks!</span>
<% else %>
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Created at</th>
            <th>Completed</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
            <tr>
                <td><strong><%= task.title %></strong></td>
                <td class="text-info"><%= task.created_at %></td>
                <td class="text-success"><%= task.completed %></td>
                <td><%= link_to "Delete", task_path(id: task.id), method: :delete, remote: true, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete task #{task.title}?" }, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_task_path(id task.id), remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**app/views/pages/home.html.erb**

```
<div id="task-list" class="container">
  <%= render 'tasks/task_list', locals: {task: @task} %>
</div>
<div id="modal" class="modal fade"></div>
```

**destroy.js.erb**

```
$('#task-list').html('<%= j(render 'task_list', locals: {task: @task} )%>');
```

**edit.js.erb**

```
m = $('#modal');
m.html('<%= j(render 'task_form', locals: {task: @task}) %>');
m.modal('show');
$('#modal').integrateDatepicker();
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Tasks
  resource :tasks, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :destory]

  root to: 'pages#home'
end
```

**Logs: delete**

```
Started DELETE "/task?id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-18 12:00:33 +0700
```

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/task"):
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.2.286) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in`call'
  web-console (2.1.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.2.286) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in`call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'

```
...
```

### rake routes

```
    Prefix    Verb URI Pattern           Controller#Action
    tasks     POST /tasks(.:format)      tasks#create
    new_task  GET  /tasks/new(.:format)  tasks#new
    edit_task GET  /tasks/edit(.:format) tasks#edit
    root      GET  /                     pages#home
```

Comment: happens to the best of us

Answer (score 2):

This must fix.

In your links try passing like,

*for edit:*

```
edit_task_path(id: task.id)
```

*for delete or show page*

```
task_path(id: task.id)
```

Comment: Thanks, and it solve the id issue. Processing by TasksController#edit as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Task Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]

Comment: But now I get this error. ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `task_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fc3a14036e0>:0x007fc3a1402740>):

Comment: so your original prob is solved? when is this appearing?

Comment: Thank you! I changed it singular resource to plural controller with you code and the "edit" works fine now!

Comment: I'm new user and not enough reputation to vote your answer up. But I appreciate a lot for your teaching Nithin

Answer (score 0):

The links to delete/edit are wrong. Correct ones would be `/tasks/1` and `/tasks/edit/1`.

In your erb, you provided the wrong links to `link_to`.

```
<td><%= link_to "Delete", tasks_path(task), method: :delete, remote: true, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete task #{task.title}?" }, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_tasks_path(task), remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</td>
```

Should be `task_path(task)` and `edit_task_path(task)`, not `task[s]_path`.

Comment: Then I get this error:
undefined method `task_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ff5eac70a28>:0x007ff5eac7f4d8>

Comment: Yes, so I changed to singular resource. Thanks Mifeng!

Answer (score 0):

Links should be:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", task_path(task), method: :delete, remote: true, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete task #{task.title}?" }, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_task_path(task), remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the age of this thread you have either already figured out how to fix this or have moved on to something else.

I noticed that in this line

```
resource :tasks, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :destory]
```

You have misspelled the word destroy. Looking at your rake routes export I don't see a DELETE action listed. Try updating the route file to this

```
resource :tasks, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :destroy]
```